# Prove $a_n = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $n=2^k$ for some $k\in N$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ diverges.

Tags: calculus

Prove $a_n = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $n=2^k$ for some $k\in N$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ diverges.

I need to prove that this diverges but I am not sure how to do so. I know that it diverges because we can see that,

$a_n = 0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1...$

My attempt:

Case 1: When $L = 0$

let $\epsilon = 1$

$$|a_n-0| < 1$$
$$|a_n| < 1$$

Case 2: When $L = 1$

$$|a_n-1| < 1$$

By Triangle Inequality:

$$|a_n+a_n-1| \le |a_n| + |a_n-1|$$
$$|a_n+a_n-1| \le 1 + 1 = 2 \neq 1$$

Thus it diverges?

I'm not sure if this is a valid proof so if anyone can help me with this, that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly know *that* the sequence diverges, and also *why* it diverges. But it looks as if you may be expected to use an  "$\epsilon$-$N$" argument.

First we proceed very informally. If our sequence had a limit $b$, then $a_n$ will be very close to $a$ whenever $n$ is large enough. But the sequence has $0$'s arbitrarily far out, and also $1$'s arbitrarily far out, and $0$ and $1$  cannot be *simultaneously*  very close to $b$.

More formally, let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{10}$. If the sequence converges to $b$, then there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|a_n-b|\lt \epsilon=\frac{1}{10}$.
From this, we derive a contradiction.

There is an integer $p\gt N$ such that $a_p=0$. Also, there is a $q=2^k\gt N$ such that $a_q=1$. Now by the triangle inequality we have
$$1=|a_p-a_q| \le |a_p-b|+|b-a_q|\lt \frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{2}{10}.$$
This is impossible, since it is not the case that $1\lt \frac{2}{10}$.

Comment: Thanks André, one question: the e is just a random number right? I can pick anything I want, or does it strictly have to be 1/10?

Comment: You are welcome. The $1/10$ was for fun. You could have picked $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, and quite a few people would do so. We would get the contradiction $1\lt \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$. We could **not** have picked $\epsilon=0.51$. For a number $b$ **can** be simultaneously at distance $\lt 0.51$ from $0$ and $1$. Or in terms of the proof, the conclusion $1\lt 0.51+0.51$ does not give a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

By diverges, we mean that the sequence doesn't converge. Note that if a sequence converges to a limit $L$ then every subsequence must converge to the same $L$.

Now you can easily see that the subsequence $a_{n_{2^k}} \rightarrow 1$ while you can find a subsequence that converges to $0$. Hence the original sequence doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go back to the definitions when you are doing proofs like this. You want to show that $a_n$ diverges, so what does it mean to diverge? A sequence converges if there exists some $L$ such that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $|L-a_n|<\epsilon$. Now, you're trying to hold that this condition *does not* hold for this sequence, so what would that mean? It would mean that for any $L$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N$ there exists some $n\geq N$ where $|L-a_n|>\epsilon$. Side-note: you should get really good at taking the negations of propositions. Let's break that last sentence down:

1. *For all* $L$
2. *there exists* $\epsilon$ such that
3. *for all* $N$
4. *there exists* $n$ such that
5. $|L-a_n|\geq \epsilon$

Now what? Well, we want to prove something about *all* $L$, so how about let's fix an arbitrary $L$ and prove that the claim holds. So fix $L$. Now we want to show that a certain $\epsilon$ exists. The trick here is to just call this value $\epsilon$ and hope we can find a specific value for it later which proves the claim. So we'll leave $\epsilon$ open right now and check the next part: *for all* $N$. Again, we're showing something holds for all $N$, so let's fix an arbitrary $N$ and prove it. Now, again, we have *there exists* *n*, so let's leave that $n$ free and hope we find something. Finally, we have $|L-a_n|\geq \epsilon$, which is really the meat of what we need to prove. So essentially, we have $L$ and $N$ fixed, and we are looking for a pair $\epsilon,n$ such that $|L-a_n|\geq \epsilon$ holds; if we can find this pair, we've proven the claim. Note that so far all of this has just been setup. The first step in a proof is figuring out exactly what you need to prove, and often that's the toughest part.

So, the question is simply, given a fixed $N$ and $L$, can we find $n$ and $\epsilon$ so that $L$ is more than $\epsilon$ away from $a_n$? To be safe, let's take epsilon to be very small and see what happens: let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ (we'll make it smaller later if we need to). We know that for *any* $n$, $a_n$ is either $0$ or $1$. So take $n$ to be the next power of 2 larger than $N$, so that $a_n=1$. Now, if $|L-1|\geq \frac{1}{2}$, we're done: we've found our pair $\epsilon,n$ such that the desired condition holds. Otherwise, we know that $a_{n+1}=0$ and $|L-1|<\frac{1}{2}$. Then, $1-L\leq |1-L| < \frac{1}{2}$. Rearranging, we get $\frac{1}{2}<L\leq|L|=|L-0|=|L-a_{n+1}|$, so we've found a pair such that the condition holds. Either way, we're done.